# cannot convert from 'void' to 'project.Models.tblUserTypes.tblUsersTypeC'

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to create new object with if statement in lambda ForEach, what is this code problem?

```
List<tblUsersTypeC> usertype = new List<tblUsersTypeC>();
usertype.Add(userToInsertList.ForEach(o => 
{
    if ((o.Counts.FollowedBy + o.Counts.Follows + o.Counts.Media) == 0) 
        new tblUsersTypeC { isPrivite = true, UserName = o.Username, WebsiteUrl = o.Website };
    else
        new tblUsersTypeC { isPrivite = false,  UserName = o.Username, WebsiteUrl = o.Website };
}));
```

Comment: why get Negative ????????

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem *is*. This is known as a "code dump question". You need to *describe* the issue, and what you have done so far to try and resolve it

Comment: the issue is in title !! i get this error on my code : cannot convert from 'void' to 'project.Models.tblUserTypes.tblUsersTypeC'

Comment: then i get this error :Description Line
Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value 76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<tblUsersTypeC> usertype = userToInsertList.Select(o => new tblUsersTypeC() 
    { 
        isPrivite = ((o.Counts.FollowedBy + o.Counts.Follows + o.Counts.Media) == 0), 
        UserName = o.Username, 
        WebsiteUrl = o.Website 
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is very strange way to create new list. Also note, that if will you add a few lines of code between `new` and `ForEach`, readability and maintainability of code will be much lower.

Comment: why ? i want to create new list in fastest way , sometimes i want add 1M users . did you know any way !?

Comment: Updated with respect to comment by @Dennis

Comment: Maintainability really.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>.ForEach` is intended to iterate through the list items and do something, using their current state. Actually, your question is yet another sample, which shows, that `ForEach` method is unnatural, non-obvious replacement for `foreach` operator.

To get new list of items, based on items from the current list, use [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)/[`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extensions:

```
var usertype = userToInsertList
    .Select(o => new tblUsersTypeC
    {
        isPrivite = (o.Counts.FollowedBy + o.Counts.Follows + o.Counts.Media) == 0, 
        UserName = o.Username, 
        WebsiteUrl = o.Website 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
userToInsertList.Select( o=> (condition) ? value1: value2);
```

or

```
userToInsertList.Select( o=> { if(condition) { return value1} else {return value2;}});
```

List.ForEach doesn't return any thing.